# How to access contents of file uploaded from <input type="file" /> without sending to server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to upload JSON file from local disk to upload chrome storage but when I use the tag  and useRef on the current value, it only returns the filename prefixed with 'C:\fakepath...'

**ImportExport Component:**

```
const ImportExport = () => {
  const uploadValue = useRef()

  const download = () => {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, res => {
      let blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(res)], {type: "application/json"})
      let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: 'download', data: url}, () => {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
      })
    })
  }

  const upload = async () => {
    let bb = new Blob([uploadValue.current.value], {type: "application/json"})
    let contents = await bb.text()
    console.log(contents) // logs 'C:\fakepath\notes.json'
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-start rounded-sm mx-auto w-1/2 shadow-md h-5/6">
      <h2 className="text-3xl m-5">Import/Export</h2>
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="import" className={styles.button}>Import</label>
        <input onChange={upload} ref={uploadValue} type="file" accept="application/json" id="import" />
        <button onClick={download}className={styles.button}>Export</button>
      </form>
      
      <h3 className="text-2xl m-3">Note:</h3>
      <p className="text-center w-1/2">This exports the data to .JSON file which can then be used to import back to chrome storage</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I've read that I can use File API or Blob API. I've tried both but none of them where able to actually access the data contained. They could only access the path 'C:\fakepath\data.json'.

I've been looking scraping the web for answers and all I could find is it looks like I need to send this to a server first. However, my app is a chrome extension and has no web server.

Can anyone help me figure this out? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: _"I've read that I can use File API or Blob API. I've tried both but none of them where able to actually access the data contained. They could only access the path 'C:\fakepath\data.json'."_ - the filename is fake, by-design, but did you actually try to read the `Blob`?

Comment: I'm aware of the fake path, it's in there for security purposes. Yes, I did try to read the Blob. I thought if I turned it into a blob, it would read the contents instead of the actual path. But the data it's working on is the value that was passed into it.

I also tried FileReader but I was getting the same thing. I'm thinking there might not be a way to work with this data on client side but MDN site says this can be manipulated by Javascript.

Most examples showed to have worked for images src using URL.createObjectURL but I've tried mine on both txt file and json file but not worked.

Comment: I've never had any problems using `HTMLInputElement.files`, with `File` and `Blob` and `FileReader`. Can you please post a minimal repro that you're confident doesn't work so I can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this (use `files[0]` instead of `value`)

```
  const upload = async () => {
    let bb = new Blob([uploadValue.current.files[0]], {type: "application/json"})
   ...
  }
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you. I've read this on MDN but couldn't put it all together.